# Np.where with optional condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For my database I need to create a new column based on a condition.
In a seperate file I have add all the conditions like this:

```
conditions = [{year: 2016, price: 30000, fuel: Petrol, result: 12},
              {year: 2017, price: 45000, fuel: Elektricity, result: 18},
              {year: 2018, price: None, fuel: Petrol, result: 14},
```

I am using the following code to add a new column

```
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == dict[year]) & (df['price'] > dict[price]) & (df['fuel description'] == dict[fuel])), dict[result], df['new_column'
```

As you see in the conditions, it is possible that one of the values is none.
This means (in this case price: none) that the formula as follows:

```
df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == dict[year]) & (df['fuel description'] == dict[fuel])), dict[result], df['new_column'
```

It is possible that multiple conditions are none, I want to prevent working with to much if and else statements but I can't figure out a way to do something in the formula that when it is none it needs to remove the condition.

Is this possible or should I just work with:

```
If dict[price] != None:
    df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == dict[year]) & (df['price'] > dict[price]) & (df['fuel description'] == dict[fuel])), dict[result], df['new_column'
else:
    df['new_column'] = np.where((df['year'] == dict[year]) & (df['fuel description'] == dict[fuel])), dict[result], df['new_column'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) the conditions to separate the creation of each condition from their application, you will need an if conditions for each optional condition, but not their combinations.

```py
from operator import and_
from functools import reduce

conditions = []
if dict['year'] != None:
    conditions.append(df['year'] == dict['year'])
if dict['price'] != None:
    conditions.append(df['price'] > dict['price'])
...

if len(conditions) != 0:
    # similar to conditions[0] & conditions[1] & ...
    df['new_column'] = np.where(reduce(and_, conditions), dict['result'], df['new_column'])  
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Never looked at it this way but definitely gonna use it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a `merge_sof`:

```
df['update_result'] = (
 pd.merge_asof(df.fillna({'price': -1}).reset_index()
                 .sort_values(by='price').drop(columns='result'),
               pd.DataFrame(conditions).fillna({'price': -1})
                 .sort_values(by='price'),
               by=['year', 'fuel'], on='price')
   .set_index('index')['result'].fillna(df['result'])
)
```

Used input:

```
   year     price         fuel  result
0  2016  456789.0       Petrol       1
1  2017   20000.0  Elektricity       2
2  2018       NaN       Petrol       3
```

Output:

```
   year     price         fuel  result
0  2016  456789.0       Petrol    12.0
1  2017   20000.0  Elektricity     2.0
2  2018       NaN       Petrol    14.0
```

Comment: Wauw I need to dive into this one, thanks!